# Passing arrays in play

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I got some problems with setting array of booleans.
I defined array in my model:

```
   @Entity
public class Ssr extends Model{

    @Id
    public int num;
    public boolean[] row1;
```

In my view file I'm creating table

```
...

<td>Network</td>        
    @for(a <- 1 to 10){
        <td>
    @checkbox(ssrForm("row1[@a]"),'_label->None)
    </td>
    }

...
```

And when I try to pass this values to next screen,values are not saved in ssr object and axception shows up:

```
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:h2:mem:play
[error] c.a.e.s.t.r.ImmutableMetaFactory - Was unable to use reflection to find
a constructor and appropriate getters forimmutable type class [Z.  The errors wh
ile looking for the getter methods follow:
[error] c.a.e.s.d.p.DeployCreateProperties - Error with models.Ssr field:row1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to use reflection to build ImmutableMeta for
class [Z.  Associated Errors trying to find a constructor and getter methods hav
e been logged
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.reflect.ImmutableMetaFactory.crea
teImmutableMeta(ImmutableMetaFactory.java:53) ~[avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.DefaultTypeManager.recursiveCreat
eScalarTypes(DefaultTypeManager.java:205) ~[avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.cr
eateProp(DeployCreateProperties.java:321) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.cr
eateProp(DeployCreateProperties.java:341) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.cr
eateProperties(DeployCreateProperties.java:128) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.cr
eateProperties(DeployCreateProperties.java:54) [avaje-ebeanorm.jar:na]
```

Should I use List instead of arrays?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found soulution. If you don't need to store your array in DB, just add "transient" keyword to variable declaration.

```
@Entity
public class Ssr extends Model{

    @Id
    public int num;
    public transient boolean[] row1;
```